# Running file-based tests on Junit 5 Platform using Apache Maven Surefire

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

I have implemented a custom `TestEngine` class that is able to discover and run unit tests from `*.csv` files (not java classes) by checking for `FileSelector` in the `EngineDiscoveryRequest` from Junit 5.

I am able to run these tests without problems using the `ConsoleLauncher` provided by the Junit team, by invoking `org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher -f build/resources/test/testfile_1.csv` (this is invoked from a gradle task because [gradle does not support resource-based testing](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4773) but that should not matter here).

Now, I am trying to run the same tests using the same custom test engine but by using maven and the surefire plugin instead of the console launcher. My current `pom.xml` looks as follows (relevant part):

```xml
<project>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>my_custom_test_engine</groupId>
            <artifactId>custom_test_engine</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0-M1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-console</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0-M1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Unfortunately, `surefire:test` does not appear to even call my test engine for discovery and just finishes with:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.626 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-20T17:00:01+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I do not have any test classes in my `src` folder, just one test file under `resources/testfile_1.csv`.

Does surefire even support file-based testing with Junit 5? If so, how can I force Surefire to call my custom test engine for test discovery?

-- Update

The discovery part of my `TestEngine` implementation looks something like this (only relevant part shown):

```java
public class MyTestEngine implements TestEngine {

    @Override
    public TestDescriptor discover(EngineDiscoveryRequest discoveryRequest, UniqueId uniqueId) {
        EngineDescriptor engineDescriptor = new EngineDescriptor(uniqueId, name);

        logger.debug("Discovering tests");

        discoveryRequest.getSelectorsByType(FileSelector.class).forEach(selector -> {
            logger.debug("Discovered: {}", selector.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
                engineDescriptor.addChild(new TestDescriptor (engineDescriptor.getUniqueId(), selector.getFile().getName()));

        });
}
```

-- Update 2
My test files are located under `src/test/resources`.

Comment: I don't see any dependency to junit-jupiter-api ? Furthermore surefire is usually responsible for finding test cases which is not the case here. Apart from that The TestEngine is the interface to offer an implementation for the test engine which be made known to JUnit Jupiter. Have you annotated your parts with `@Testable` annotation? Do you have a link to your project?

Comment: Well, thats the point. I dont *want* to use Jupiter because I have my own `TestEngine` implementation. This implementation does not rely on test classes, but on test files (i.e. csv files), so there can not be any `@Testable` annotation. I updated my question with same sample code of my `TestEngine` implementation.

Comment: Not accurate. You don't want to use the junit-jupiter-engine but you want to use JUnit Jupiter platform. Furthermore you need to use at least junit-jupiter-api to trigger surefire to load the correct base parts. Apart from that I'm not sure if this will work at all cause surefire relies on identifying on classes which you don't have. Furthermore is the question where you have located the csv file? in `src/test/resources` ? Apart I'm curious what kind of advantage a CSV files has over real written unit tests in Java code?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but according to the Junit user guide, JUnit Jupiter is the combination of the new programming model and the extension model. I am fairly certain that I need neither of these, as my `TestEngine` works perfectly fine when running with the `ConsoleLauncher`. The console launcher is run in a gradle project, where I only have dependencies to `junit-platform-engine` and `junit-platform-console`. Regarding the use case: The csv files will be automatically generated during runtime. They are not "unit tests" in the traditional sense as they are used for test-based code search.

Comment: But those dependencies you don't have given in the maven project?

Comment: Those dependencies get pulled in as transitive dependencies from the `custom_test_engine` dependency.

Comment: You should add them directly cause surefire does not search for all that transitive (If I correctly rememeber).

Comment: I just tried it with explicitly adding them as direct dependencies (updated my code in the question), but the result is the same. 
Maybe surefire just does not support resource-based testing on the Junit 5 platform?

Comment: @mlxyz I think you’re right in assuming that Surefire does not support file based test discovery directly. You may want to change your engine so that it uses an annotated class which will then load the file. I assume that the cucumber engine is doing it that way.

Comment: We in the Apache Maven are aware of this issue and this fix in our plan. The Surefire and Failsafe was never designed for running the CSV. It does not matter what version you use, the plugin was always operating with classes and methods. We are working on an abstract description of a test which can be anything e.g. UniqueID as for JUnit5 as well as running files, etc. This feature requires big changes to rework the internals of the plugin.BTW all of this is mentioned in the ROAD MAP for SUREFIRE, please see the front page: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Credit goes to @johanneslink for pointing me in the right direction.

Surefire indeed does not support resource-based testing (see also [this issue](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1632)).
What I did instead (as @johanneslink advised), was to create an empty class, which can be detected by surefire so that the custom `TestEngine` is invoked:

```java
public class TestInitializer {
}
```

Then, in my `TestEngine`, I check for `ClassSelector` and discover the resource-based tests:

```java
discoveryRequest.getSelectorsByType(ClassSelector.class).forEach(selector -> {
            if (selector.getClassName().equals(TestInitializer.class.getName())) {
                discoverTests(new File(System.getenv("test_dir")), engineDescriptor);
            }
        });
```

The actual directory where my test files are located is specified with the environment variable `test_dir`.

Then, for actually using the custom `TestEngine`, modify your `pom.xml` as follows:

```xml
   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <dependenciesToScan>
                        <dependency>
                            my_custom_test_engine:custom_test_engine
                        </dependency>
                    </dependenciesToScan>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/TestInitializer*
                        </include>
                    </includes>
                    <environmentVariables>
                        <test_dir>target/test-classes
                        </test_dir>
                    </environmentVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

The `dependenciesToScan` property will ensure, that surefire scans the dependency containing the `TestInitializer` class.

**Note that the latest version `3.0.0-M5` of `maven-surefire-plugin` appears to be broken in this regard as the tests will be discovered and run, but surefire will not pick up on the results. Use `2.22.2` instead.**

Comment: @mlxyx Sorry but you are wrong. The Surefire and Failsafe was never designed for CSV. It does not matter what version you use, the plugin was always operating with classes and methods. We are working on an abstract description of a test which can be anything, e.g. UniqueID as for JUnit5 as well as running files. This feature requires big changes to rework the internals of the plugin.BTW all of this is mentioned in the ROAD MAP for SUREFIRE, please see the front page with the road map: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/

Comment: @tibor17 Please read the answer completely. My workaround abstracts away the fact that I am testing csv files meaning Surefire still assumes I am testing classes. This approach *does* work with version 2.22.2 but not with 3.0.0-M5, hence my comment.
Also: I literally said in the beginning of my answer that Surefire does not support file-based testing.